# verificar consulta em 2 tabelas ao mesmo tempo com mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas no meu BD (mysql), onde:

1º Tabela: `CADASTROS`
Com os seguintes campos: `ID, NOME, IDADE, CIDADE`

2º Tabela: `FUNCIONARIO`
Com os seguintes campos: `ID, ID_CADASTRO, PROFISSAO, SALARIO`

Realizando uma consulta na tabela `CADASTROS` ordenando pelo `NOME`:

```
SELECT * FROM CADASTROS ORDER BY NOME ASC
```

Como realizar uma pesquisa que me retorne apenas os registro existentes na tabela `CADASTROS` sem correspondência com a tabela `FUNCIONARIO`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderá fazer assim:

```
select * from cadastros a
where not exists(select * from funcionario b where a.id = b.id_cadastro)
```

ou assim:

```
select * from cadastros a
left join funcionario b on b.id_cadastro = a.id
where b.id_cadastro is null
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou 100% aqui :)

Answer (score 1):

Para trazer todos os registros da tabela CADASTRO menos os IDs que estão na tabela funcionário você deve escrever assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastros where id not in ( select id from funcionario ) ORDER BY nome ASC
```

Comment: tentei sa sua forma mas não deu certo, a forma so ismael funcionou comigo, de qualquer forma vlw ;)

Comment: Qual é o erro que você recebe ao executar esse select que te passei?

Comment: nao retornou nenhum resultado

Comment: Isso significa que todos os ids que estão na tabela cadastro estão na tabela funcionário.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderá desenvolver da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro as c JOIN funcionario as f ON (c.id=f.id_cadastro)
```

Desta forma, você poderá exibir os dados da outra tabela também, você pode colocar no * do FROm, os campos que deseja buscar... ex:

```
SELECT c.nome, f.profissao FROM cadastro as c JOIN funcionario as f ON (c.id=f.id_cadastro)
```

Neste caso, irá retornar apenas os campos nome e profissão (nome de uma e profissão da outra).

Espero ter ajudado!